# Packaging JAX-WS web services

Tags: java, web-services, maven, war, packaging

I have several web services interfaces (let's call them A, B, C) and their implementations (AImpl, BImpl, CImpl) implemented using JAX-WS. They are deployed as a war (project-ws.war).

But for some reason I need to have the interfaces and the implementations deployed in different artifacts (project-ws-interfaces.jar and project-ws-impl.war), with the implementations war having a dependency on the interfaces jar.

I can't find a way to do it so. All my attempts result in the war unable to resolve the web services interfaces at deploy time. Is it even possible to package the interfaces and the implementations in different artifacts ?

Comment: When you say `Deployed in different artifacts` you mean deployed at the maven repository (mvn deploy) or deployed at the web-server (e.g. tomcat)?

Comment: It would be helpful anyway to give some details about the list of `All my attempts...` you mention in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like basic maven job.

Create an API artifact, packaged as a jar :

```
<groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>ws-api/artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Install it in your local maven repo with *mvn install* or, if you have a private repository for your company, deploy it with *mvn deploy*

Then, in your implementation project, include it as a dependency :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Hope it is helpful.